# Adding recent posts to homepage and aligning elements

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was so curious in creating themes for WordPress and thought to create one for myself (finally)

Seems like as much as I try, I can't get the website to display my recent posts -> 2 lines | 2 posts

Here is the PHP I'm using

```html
<div id="blogg" class="row">
<div class="container">
    <div id="blogg_innlegg_left"><div class="well">
        <ul>
            <?php $left_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=2' ); ?>
            <?php while ($left_query -> have_posts()) : $left_query -> the_post(); ?>
            <div class="thumb">
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="title">
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </ul>
    </div></div>
    <div id="blogg_innlegg_right"><div class="well">
        <ul>
            <?php $right_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=5&offset=2' ); ?>
            <?php while ($right_query -> have_posts()) : $right_query -> the_post(); ?>
            <div class="thumb">
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="title">
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </ul>
    </div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS I'm using

```css
#blogg_innlegg_left, #blogg_innlegg_right {
    display: flex;
    .well{
        width: 100%;
        ul {
            columns: 2;
            -webkit-columns: 2;
            -moz-columns: 2;
            list-style: none;
        }
        .thumb {
            float: left;
        }
        .title {
            float: left;
            max-width:100px;
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I try to align them, it goes wrong, even the mobile responsive.

I want to achieve the exact match as in wpbeginner.com with the recent posts on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

> The Loop is the default mechanism WordPress uses for outputting posts
> through a theme’s template files.
>
> **The basic loop is:**
>
> ```
> <?php 
> if ( have_posts() ) : 
>     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
>         // Display post content
>     endwhile; 
> endif; 
> ?>
> ```

*Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/*

Here you're trying to use two different loop, which is, **in this case unnecessary**. It seems to me that you have currently 2 problems, you're struggling in understanding the Wordpress loop, and you can't figure out how handle css. I would suggest you have a bit of a read on both subjects.

Using our simple loop and `the_title()` & `the_content()` functions, we can start to display our posts on the frontend.

### **EDIT: As per your comments you wanted 2 different columns, i've edited the post with your specifications.**

```
<main>
<section>
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 2 ) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <article>
      <h1><?php the_title()?></h1>
      <?php the_content() ?>
    </article>
  <?php endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</section>
<section>
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'offset' => 2 ) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <article>
      <h1><?php the_title()?></h1>
      <?php the_content() ?>
    </article>
  <?php endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</section>
</main>
```

Now that our 2 posts are being displayed on the front end we would like to styled them in a way that let us put 2 post in 2 different columns.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
section {
  max-width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
main {
  clear: both;
}
```

There is no "one way" to do this, for example you could achieve the same thing with `display: flex;`.

---

### Learn More

- Read about `the_title()` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/.
- Read about `the_content()` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/.
- CSS Box Sizing @ https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp
- CSS Layout - float and clear @ https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: The idea is to display 2 posts per column.

Comment: @Crow I've edited the post, now using 2 columns, 2 articles per columns

Comment: `showposts` as been deprecated since Wordpress 2.5-ish, you should now use `posts_per_page`. Also, arguments are passed to the Wordpress query via an `array()`.  You can learn more about the WP_Query here @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Comment: Tried, but didn't work again. The post's text isn't going inline and also they are not being affected properly.

Comment: It has been tested and it's working on my end.